# Enabling query string for table filtering

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I want the URL to include a query string when I filter a table to share it with others easily. I watched a video that has been shared that demonstrated this feature, and I was wondering how I can enable it, as can be seen in the video https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/7129#issuecomment-1661456931
I use table builder on a public page, not table builder inside a panel.